# ¿Cómo cargar contenido desde BD en CheckButtons, dependiendo de una selección usando un Select? PHP-MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

espero que este bien.

Miren estoy creando un Kardex web, tengo 2 tablas relacionadas ya creadas:

tabla_uniformes (id_uniforme, descripcion,stock, area_id)
tabla_areas     (id_area, area)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo es un "Selec option" en el cual estoy cargando las areas desde mi bd.

```
<select class="form-control" >
          <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
          <?php
          $query = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_areas");
          $query->execute();
          $data = $query->fetchAll();

          foreach ($data as $valores):
          echo '<option value="'.$valores["id_area"].'">'.$valores["area"].'</option>';
          endforeach;
          ?>
          </select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que deseo es que, dependiendo el área seleccionada, me muestra los uniformes pero en checkboxes,
Actualmente llamo a TODOS uniformes y los muestro en los checkbox de la siquiente manera:

```
   <?php       
           $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes";
           $consulta=$bd->query($query);
                  
              while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
              {
          
                    echo '<li> <input type="checkbox" id="'.$fila["id_uniforme"].'"> <label 
        for="'.$fila["id_uniforme"].'">'.$fila["descripcion"].'</label> </li>';
              }
          ?>
     </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Capas tenga que usar algún script que me guarde la variable id_area y luego esa me sirva para para hacer mi SELECT, pero no se me ocurre algo, y tener un div oculto que se muestre cuado ya se seleccione el area. Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Si lo que deseas es guardar los datos de id_area podrías hacerlo guardando el id_area en un array y luego cuando quieras utilizar esos datos los sacas del array que tienes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si entendí tu problema, pero prueba con ajax, seria algo así...

```
<select id="area">
    <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
    
        <div id="uniformes">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox"> Este es mi primer checkbox</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="second_checkbox"> <label for="cbox2">Este es mi segundo checkbox</label>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#area").change(function() {
                id = $('#area option:selected').val();
                $.ajax({
                    data: id, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                    url: 'uniformes.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                    type: 'post', //método de envio
                    success: function(data) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                        if (data) {
                            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                                $("#uniformes").append(
                                    '<sapan><input type="checkbox" name="' + value['ID_ALAR06'] + '" class="checkArea" value="' + value['ID_ALAR06'] + '"> ' + value['ARE_DESCRIPCION'] + '</span><br>');
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    
    
        <?php
        //unifromes.php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE aera_id=" . (int)$request->id;
        $consulta = $bd->query($query);
    
        echo $consulta;
    
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la ayuda amigo Gabriel Nuñez, segui tu consejo usando Ajax. Muestro el código de como lo hice.

Ajax para elegir el id, y mandarlo como post al cargar_uniforme.php

```
  $("#area").change(function() {               
          var id = $('#area').val()           
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post', //método de envio
              url: 'cargar_uniformes.php?id='+id, //archivo que recibe la peticion                   
              data:{},                                             
                success: function(data) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve                    
                  $('#uniformes').html(data);                       
                }
            });
        });
```

Y este es mi cargar_uniformes.php :

```
<?php  
$id = $_GET['id'];
include("../includes/conexion.php");                    
    
$query = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE area_id =".$id);                        
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$html="";
foreach ($data as $value)
$html.='<li> <input type="checkbox" id="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'"> <label 
for="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'">'.$value["descripcion"].'</label> </li>';
echo $html;
?>
```

El resultado seria esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que si me genero una duda es porque en el archivo cargar_uniformes.php, al leer la variable "id" que me envia el ajax, tengo que usar el metodo GET, ya que si uso el POST
no me lee esa variable "id".

$id = $_GET['id'];

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba pasar el id así { id }

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#area").change(function() {
                    var id = $('#area').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET', 
                        url: 'cargar_uniformes.php',                  
                        data: {
                            id
                        },
                        success: function(data) 
                            $('#uniformes').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```